# Why is there the first 看 in 她看都没看过我一眼?

Tags: grammar, usage

From 标准教程HSK4上 (page 93):

> 她看都没看过我一眼，怎么样才能使她喜欢我呢？

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%A5%B9%E7%9C%8B%E9%83%BD%E6%B2%A1%E7%9C%8B%E8%BF%87%E6%88%91%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC%EF%BC%8C%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E6%A0%B7%E6%89%8D%E8%83%BD%E4%BD%BF%E5%A5%B9%E5%96%9C%E6%AC%A2%E6%88%91%E5%91%A2%EF%BC%9F) is not great here, but it gives some idea of how it works.  I think it translates to something like:

> She has never even glanced at me, how can I get her to like me?

I don't understand how the first part 她看都没看过我一眼 pieces together.

I think the logic is something like:

1. 一眼 = a glance
2. **看**一眼 = a glance at
3. 看**我**一眼 a glance at me
4. 看**过**我一眼 glanced at me once
5. **没**看过我一眼 never glanced at me once
6. **都**没看过我一眼 never even <s>once</s> glanced at me
7. **看**都没看过我一眼 ???
8. **她**看都没看过我一眼 She has never even glanced at me

So...

**Question**: Why is there the first 看 in 她看都没看过我一眼?

Baidu gives some examples where we just drop the 看, but they're relatively rare (so could be erroneous), e.g.:

> 自始至终，她都没看过我一眼！  ([link](https://www.55duba.com/du58465/15946744.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common pattern used for emphasizing that something "hasn't even been...":

> v + 都没有 + v

- 动都没有动 = hasn't even been touched
- 看都没有看 = hasn't even been looked at
- 翻都没有翻 = hasn't even been flipped through

Comment: I can hear the question coming: What's the difference between 没 and 没有？想都没想到 。。。，but that's another thread!

Comment: @Pedroski I believe that they are essentially the same. If you really want to be pedantic you could say v + 没有 + v= [you] haven’t even (...) and v + 没 + v = [you] didn’t even (...), but again this is splitting hairs.

Answer (score 0):

the translate is correct

她都没看过我一眼
She never saw me

她看都没看过我一眼
why? why? why! why!She has never, never, ever, even glanced at me once T.T

try not to explain each word [x都沒x] is just use to emphases